# OnAppearing() method being triggered at wrong time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, maui

I have a Maui application, so called Product_Service where you can add product/items, remove or change them.
Now to the problem, here i set my MainPage to HomePage

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
        {
        InitializeComponent();    

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }
}
```

in the HomePage.xaml.cs i have OnAppearing method

```cs
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
      To Do;
}
```

The HomePage displays collectionView with my items and add button which executes the following command ( Navigates to my another page)

```cs
public async Task GoToAddProductCommandExecute()
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddProductPage());
}
```

On AddProductPage i have a button to add image using MediaPicker, Entry for Name, Entry for Category and DatePicker to choose date;
and the problem occurs when i click on ChooseImage button which executes following command  private async Task

```cs
AddImageCommandExecute()
{
    var image = await uploadImage.OpenMediaPickerAsync();

    if (image != null)
    {
        var imageFile = await uploadImage.Upload(image);
        var imagePath = await uploadImage.SaveImageToFile(imageFile.byteBase64);
        Image = imagePath;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Image));
        Upload_Image_Instance.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => uploadImage.ByteArrayToStream(uploadImage.StringToByteBase64(imageFile.byteBase64)));
    }
}
public async Task<FileResult> OpenMediaPickerAsync()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
        {
            Title = "Please pick a photo"
        });

        if (result.ContentType == "image/png" ||
           result.ContentType == "image/jpeg" ||
           result.ContentType == "image/jpg")
            return result;
        else
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error Type Image", "Please choose a new image", "Ok");
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

basically the main 2 parts, when the media picker is opens and i choose any image by clicking on it and OnAppearing method executes in my Home.xaml.cs even though im on AddProductPage. Then i have a button AddProduct which inserts following date into database and pops AddProductPage and only now the OnAppearing() method should be called since the HomePage Appears, but now it doesn't get triggered. It may be hard to udnerstand but English isn't my first language and i tried to describe as best as i can.

I tried using break points to find where the problem is and it happens in the AddImageCommandExecute, right after it finishes the OnAppearing method of HomePage is now triggered. Also i set my MainPage to a new Page what i named LoginPage which contained only 1 button executing command that does
  `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());`
now when i click the ChooseImage button on my AddProductPage and select one it works as expected, the OnAppearing() method in HomePage.xaml.cs isn't being triggered till i click on AddProduct button and the HomePage appears

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: There is a bug, [OnAppearing not triggered when going back from Modal page](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8513) that is tagged with `fixed-in-7.0.81`. Make sure that you have Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5.4 or newer.

Comment: Two possible workarounds: 1) Use [community toolkit Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) to send message to the page that is appearing. 2) Use `Navigation.PushAsync` instead of using Modal.